# is it meaningful to integrate jQuery and JSF? if so on what contexts I need to use jQuery and JSF techs?

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am practising JSF. Well I understand that JSF is a serverside component framework in web application development. Well I am in confusion that if JSF provides all those UI components to develop web based application then is it meaningful to integrate jQuery and JSF? if so on what contexts I need to use jQuery and JSF techs?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer are depended on your aims. JSF is allmost always used with some framework such as RichFaces, MyFaces, etc. And they usually provide it's own js api. So usually jquery are not needed. But, if you want to develop a custom UI component you can use jquery to build it.

Comment: RichFaces and PrimeFaces use jQuery behind the scenes, I haven't worked with other frameworks yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use WebSphere 7.0 in my organization. I did use Jquery with JSF to accomplish some tasks. Because a lot of these frameworks don't work well with WebSphere. And a lot others need a lot of customization which my admin will never allow. Also the interface language is Arabic which makes another set of these frameworks useless to me.
One other reason is that you may need it for one specific task which doesn't need you to overload your application with one of these frameworks since they add hooks and stuff into the lifecycle which may affect the scalability of your pages.
But you have to note that working with these frameworks makes life a lot easier than working jsf with jquery to do the same task.
In the end, it's your call.